# Max retries exceeded with url error while running the code?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I write this code to scrap this particular page but it constantly gave

> error "requests.exceptions.SSLError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='rcms.assam.gov.in', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url: /Show_Reports.aspx?RID=86 (Caused by
> SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
> certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
> (_ssl.c:1129)')))"

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


url = "https://rcms.assam.gov.in/Show_Reports.aspx?RID=86"
page = requests.get(url)
soup = bs(page.text,"lxml")
```

Answer (score 10):

At your own risk you can do this:

```
page = requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

Comment: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'rcms.assam.gov.in'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/1.26.x/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  warnings.warn(

Comment: it gave this error

Comment: That is not an error. It's a warning

Comment: so how can i resolve that so i can scrap data from that page

Comment: You can disable the warning with *urllib3.disable_warnings()* However, that's the least of your worries. You're going to have to figure out how to bypass the Captcha

Answer (score 1):

Download the website certificate to your local computer, and then

```
page = requests.get(url, verify="path to certificate")
```

Comment: And how would one go about downloading the website certificate?

Answer (score 1):

As said by Fred, do it at your own risk.
To disable the warning along with `verify=False` use the below code.

```
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
from urllib3 import disable_warnings

disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

page = requests.get(url, verify=False)
```